# Bounding the number of certain (translation) subsets in $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ with respect to given subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, semigroups, monoid

Let $\mathbb N = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ be the monoid of natural numbers with zero.
Suppose $S \subseteq \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ be some subset such that the number of sets of the form $\{ (i,j) \mid (i+n, j+m) \in S \}$ for fixed $(n,m)$ is finite, so all those sets could be referenced by a finite number of tuples $(n_1, m_1), \ldots, (n_k, m_k)$ (lets call them the translations sets with respect to $S$). Now take the smallest submonoid $M = \langle S \rangle$ generated by $S$. If the family of subsets
$$
 \{ \{ (i, j) \mid (i + n, j + m) \in M\} \mid n,m \ge 0  \}
$$
is finite, could it be somehow bounded in the number of translation subsets of this form for $S$?

**Remark**: The assumption that the translation sets for $M$ are finite is necessary, as in general it could be infinite, take $S = \{(1,1)\}$, then $M = \{ (0,0), (1,1), (2,2), \ldots \}$ and so we have the translation sets
$$
 \{ (i, j) \mid i = j \},\quad\{ (i,j) \mid i = j + 1 \},\quad\{ (i,j) \mid i = j + 2 \}, \ldots
$$
where the first is with $(n,m) = (0,0)$, the second with $(n,m) = (1,0)$ and so on.

Comment: I don't get your remark. Don't you have infinitely many translation subsets w.r.t. $S$?

Comment: Yes! In this example we have infinitely many, but there are cases when it is finite indeed (should I present one?), and this question is concerned with the case when it is finite (unlike in the remark, which should show that it could be infinite).

Comment: What's an example where it is finite for S and infinite for M?

Comment: Now I'm confused. Don't you have finitely many translation subsets w.r.t $S$, specifically five? $\{(1,1)\},\{(1,0)\},\{(0,1)\},\{(0,0)\},\emptyset.$

Comment: I agree with Dap. In your remark, the number of sets of the form $\{ (i,j) \mid (i+n, j+m) \in S \}$ with certain nonnegative $(n,m)$ is 5, but the number of sets of the form $\{ (i,j) \mid (i+n, j+m) \in M\}$ is infinite. Your remark seems misleading...

Comment: @Helmut yea, my bad. I don't know why he agreed with me in his comment, but I don't see why his remark (in the question) is misleading. Isn't it a good remark?

Comment: Sorry, in the initial comment I overlooked that @mathworker21 asked for $S$. In the example we have five translation subsets for $S$ (as given by @Dap), but infinitely many for $M$. Sorry for the confusion. You all got it right.